# JSON return value incorrectly parsed in objective C: iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, json

```
{"Overviews":
    [
     {"AAAA": [
               {"Generala": "sometext",
                "Generalb": "sometext",
                "Generalc": "sometext"}
              ],
     "BBBB": [
               {"Generala": "sometext",
                "Generalb": "sometext",
                "Generalc": "sometext"}
              ]
      }
     ]
 }
```

Hi I used SBJson to parse this json. When I assigned NSArray *json = [jsonObject valueForKey:@"Overviews"];. The hierarchy of data didn't go well.  I used one NSDictionary, 2 NSArray and 1 NSString to parse Generala.

My goal is to parse the data "Generala" like this:

```
NSDictionary *data = [overviews valueForObject:@"AAAA"];
NSString *generals = [data valueForObject:@"Generala"];
```

What have I done wrong in the json file? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSArray *dataArray = [overviews objectForKey:@"AAAA"];
NSDictionary *dataDict = [dataArray objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *generals = [dataDict objectForKey:@"Generala"];
```

This will get you to the correct value, But as you can see I had to "Hard code" the index "0". You would want some logic in there to get to the specific array.

or Change your json to:

```
{"Overviews":
     {"AAAA":
               {"Generala": "sometext",
                "Generalb": "sometext",
                "Generalc": "sometext"},
     "BBBB":
               {"Generala": "sometext",
                "Generalb": "sometext",
                "Generalc": "sometext"}
      }
}
```

and use:
    NSDictionary *dataDict = [overviews objectForKey:@"AAAA"];
    NSString *string = [dataDict objectForKey:@"Generala"];

Answer (score 2):

You've got superfluous arrays in there.  Overviews is an array with one element in - a dictionary.  It should just be the dictionary.  The same applies for AAAA and BBBB - they are arrays containing a single dictionary, when they should just be dictionaries.

Basically, just delete all of the square brackets in your JSON.

Answer (score 1):

Your source is a dictionary of one entry, which entry contains an array of one entry, which entry contains a dictionary of two entries, which entries each contain an array of one entry, which entry contains a dictionary of three entries.

I suspect this is exactly how the JSON parser parsed it.